# Rbind-ing data.tables with NA values

Tags: r, data.table, rbind

I have a big `data.table` with about 40 columns, and I need to add a record for which I only have 3 of the 40 columns (the rest will be just `NA`). To make a reproducible example:

```
require(data.table)
data(iris)
setDT(iris)

# this works (and is the expected result):
rbind(iris, list(6, NA, NA, NA, "test"))
```

The problem is I have 37+ empty columns (the data I want to input is in the 1st, 2nd and 37th columns of the variable). So, I need to `rep` some of the `NA`s. But if I try:

```
rbind(iris, list(6, rep(NA, 3), "test"))
```

It won't work (sizes are different). I could do

```
rbind(iris, list(c(6, rep(NA, 3), "test")))
```

But it will (obviously) coerce the whole first column to char. I've tried unlisting the list, inverting the `list(c(` sequence (it only accepts lists), and haven't found anything yet.

Please note that this is not a duplicate of the (several) posts about rbind data.tables, as I'm able to do that. What I haven't been able to, is to maintain proper data classes while doing it **and** using `rep(NA, x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do...

```
rbind(data.table(iris), c(list(6), logical(3), list("test")))

     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
151:          6.0          NA           NA          NA      test
```

`logical(n)` is the same as `rep(NA, n)`. I wrapped `iris` in `data.table()` so `rbindlist` is used instead of `rbind.data.frame` and `"test"` is treated as a new factor level instead of an invalid level.

---

I think there are better ways to go, though, like...

```
newrow = setDT(iris[NA_integer_, ])
newrow[, `:=`(Sepal.Length = 6, Species = factor("test")) ]
rbind(data.table(iris), newrow)

# or

rbind(data.table(iris), list(Sepal.Length = 6, Species = "test"), fill=TRUE)
```

These approaches are clearer and don't require fiddling with column counting.

I prefer the `newrow` way, since it leaves a table I can inspect to review the data transformation.

Comment: Another too-clever-by-half idea: `data.table(iris)[c(1:.N, NA)][.N, \`:=\`(Sepal.Length = 6, Species = factor("test"))][]`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `replicate`

```
rbind(iris, c(6, replicate(3, NA, simplify = FALSE), "test"))
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
#  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
#  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
#  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
#  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
# ---                                                            
#147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
#148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
#149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
#150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
#151:          6.0          NA           NA          NA      test
```

---

Or as @Frank commented

```
rbind(iris, c(6, as.list(rep(NA, 3)), "test"))
```